# how to trigger azure pipelines through rest api

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to trigger a specific Azure pipeline through REST API.
I have checked [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) . So the core message will be:

```
curl -x POST  $username:$personalaccesstoken https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Here, i cannot get find the **$pipelineId** anywhere in azure devops.

I have tried to Get Pipeline with REST APIs but the answer doesn't give me pipelineId. I have tried to create pipeline with `az pipelines create` to get the **pipelineId** in the result but it keeps asking me to az login although i do az login succesfully at first:

> Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login
> command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if
> using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see
> https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563230/how-do-i-identify-my-azuredevops-id-for-a-pipeline-in-ado-pipelines) but it doesn't give the answer.

Honestly, if you have any idea me on how to find the pipelineId or any other method to trigger pipeline with REST API, you are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start a new build, you may try to use this API: [Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

The definition id you can find in the URL of your build definition (as Krzysztof mentioned) or in the pipeline properties (in classic builds).

URL

[image]

Properties of the classic pipeline:

[image]

Then you can start a new build with powershell as example:

```
$user = ""
$token = "your_token"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$org = "org_name"
$teamProject = "team_project_name"
$defId = "build_definition_id"

$restApiRunBuild = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=$defId&api-version=6.1-preview.6"


function InvokePostReques ($PostUrl, $body)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Body $body
}

$result = InvokePostReques $restApiRunBuild ""

$result
```

Comment: When I use this, I get "This request expects an object in the request body, 
but nothing was supplied"

Comment: Yeah, this answer doesn't work as it completely ignores the required body. The link in the question actually explains everything (including the body) except that `pipelineId` == `definitionId`.

Comment: @ChristianDavén Yes, it works only with Definition ID in the URL

Answer (score 3):

`pipelineId` is equal to `definitionId`

So please go to your pipeline and check url like this `https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps%20Manual/_build?definitionId=177`.

Or use this endpoint to get list of deifnitions:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1
```