# Trigger DevOps pipeline before another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, cicd

We have the following 3 pipelines:

- CI
- CD (Dev/ Qa /Prod)
- Integration Tests (Dev/ Qa)

When we run the integration tests against an environment, is there any way to ensure the CD pipeline has been ran first for the given environment, and if not, run it?

If 2 people are working on different branches we would need to ensure that their specific branch is the last one deployed before running the integration tests against that branch? Is this possible?

Comment: These things should not be separate pipelines. They should be stages within a single pipeline.

Comment: Even if they were different stages within a single pipeline, how could we ensure that the deploy has ran before the Integration tests? For example, the Int Test stage fails and we choose to re-run that stage, but another developer has already deployed some changes elsewhere and now the integration tests are actually running against a different environment.

Comment: Each feature branch should have its own separate temporary integration test environment that's stood up and torn down as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> Trigger DevOps pipeline before another pipeline

As workaround, we could add a inline powershell task in the `Integration Tests` pipeline (before the test task) to call the REST API [Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to trigger the pipeline `CD` and monitor the states of this pipeline until the status is complete, otherwise, wait for `30` seconds, and then loop again until the status of the pipeline `CD` is complete.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=$defId&api-version=6.0
```

You could check [my previous similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815516/is-it-possible-to-run-a-final-stage-in-azure-pipelines-without-knowing-how-man/65821917#65821917) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930191/how-to-trigger-azure-pipelines-through-rest-api) for some more details.