# Trigger Azure DevOps CI/CD through powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

How can we trigger CI/CD pipelines through powershell script?

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as a new contributor. You need to describe in more detail what you want to accomplish, and just as importantly, what you've tried. Searching for "powershell azure devops rest api" here or in Google will return a lot of good material.

Comment: I'm able to run build with the powershell script in the below mentioned link but I'm unable to run release with the powershell script...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be use [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/build?view=azure-cli-latest#az_pipelines_build_queue) if is isntalled and

```
az pipelines build queue
```

Here you jave docs [Get started with Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)

Another option would [rest API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64930711/2347999) you have an example in powershell.